# Scroll bar issue in java script and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to measure the total height of the page ( some expandable options are included ) and depending upon that i have to adjust the Scroll bar of the window.

```
function autoResize(id)
{
    document.getElementById(id).height = 0;
    Newheight = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight + 50;
     if(Newheight > 800) {
        document.getElementById(id).height = (Newheight) + "px";  
     } 
     else {       
        document.getElementById(id).height = 800 + "px";
     }
}
```

If i use this code, I am getting more space at the bottom of the page. Kindly share your views on this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are adding 50 to your height. Sure that isn't the problem?

Shouldn't this:

```
Nheight = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight + 50;
```

Be this:

```
Nheight = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document;
```

Other than that, it's a little hard to see what you're doing. What's `newHeight`, for example?

Comment: Actually i am  comparing the height of the content in a window with the maximum height defined .. After that i am calling this function onLoad="autoResize('mainFrame')  like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the line:

```
if(newheight > 800) {
```

to be:

```
if(Nheight > 800) {
```

No? If not then what is newheight?